# .Net Deep cloning - what is the best way to do that?

Tags: c#, .net, clone

I need to perform deep cloning on my complex object model. What do you think is the best way to do that in .Net?
I thought about serializing / Deserializing
no need to mention that `MemberwiseClone` is not good enough.

Comment: Be really careful; is this what you really mean? Circular references between objects can quickly cause issues with deep cloning.

Comment: this does it without serialization http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deep%20Cloning&referringTitle=Home

Comment: UltraMapper https://www.nuget.org/packages/UltraMapper/

Answer (score 15):

If you control the object model, then you can write code to do it, but it is a lot of maintenance. There are lots of problems, though, which mean that unless you need **absolutely** the fastest performance, then serialization is often the most manageable answer.

This is one of the cases where `BinaryFormatter` works acceptably; normally I'm not a fan (due to the issues with versioning etc) - but since the serialized data is for immediate consumption this isn't an issue.

If you want it a bit faster (but without your own code), then `protobuf-net` may help, but requires code changes (to add the necessary metadata etc). And it is tree-based (not graph-based).

Other serializers (`XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`) are also fine, but if it is *just* for clone, they may not offer much over `BinaryFormatter` (except perhaps that `XmlSerializer` doesn't need `[Serializable]`.

So really, it depends on your exact classes and the scenario.

Comment: Perhaps a link to example might be nice. Im using UWP and I cant use BinaryFormatter. XML serializer is given below by Marty. Im curious about DataContractSerializer and protobuf-net.

Answer (score 10):

If you are running code in a Partial Trust environment such as the Rackspace Cloud you will likely be restricted from using the BinaryFormatter.  The XmlSerializer can be used instead.

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xs.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;

        return (T)xs.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when some properties of the cloned object are interfaces (e.g. IEnumerable, IList etc.). Throws an exception.

Answer (score 5):

Example of deep cloning from msdn magazine:

```
    Object DeepClone(Object original)
    {
        // Construct a temporary memory stream
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        // Construct a serialization formatter that does all the hard work
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // This line is explained in the "Streaming Contexts" section
        formatter.Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone);

        // Serialize the object graph into the memory stream
        formatter.Serialize(stream, original);

        // Seek back to the start of the memory stream before deserializing
        stream.Position = 0;

        // Deserialize the graph into a new set of objects
        // and return the root of the graph (deep copy) to the caller
        return (formatter.Deserialize(stream));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the really good article [C# Object Clone Wars](http://developerscon.blogspot.com/2008/06/c-object-clone-wars.html). I found a very interest solution there: [Copyable: A framework for copying or cloning .NET objects](http://ox.no/software/copyable)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to implement the System.IClonable interface in your object and all its fields that also needs custom deep cloning capabilities. Then you implement the [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone.aspx) method to return a deep copy of your object and its members.

Comment: There are still recommendations against this, and I agree with them.  IClonable on one object may mean deep, while on another it is shallow.  There is no way to discern when making a call. Of course, this is really not completely applicable to an internal project, but isn't a bad practice to recognize early.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [AltSerialize](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AltSerializer.aspx) which in many cases is faster than the .Net serializer. It also provides caching and custom attributes to speed up serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to implement this manually. It will be really faster than any other generic methods. Also, there are a lot of libraries for this operation (You can see some list with performance benchmarks [here](https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner#performance)).

By the way, BinaryFormatter is very slow for this task and can be good only for testing.