# Deep Clone using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

How to create Deep Clone from objects returned via Entity Framework ? The source object also have some other collections associated with it. In other words, how to clone an entity returned from Entity Framework ?

Comment: As any ohter objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251277/net-deep-cloning-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like how we deep clone any other objects. You need override the clone on source object and provide a implementation by copying each memberwise.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx
- [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Comment: There are various other approaches to it, refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically