# How to Deep Clone/Copy and entity in entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm working on an application that uses Entity Framework 4.0 (and as far as i know we cannot change it).

I need to make deep copies of object, in the case the users selects and object it will get a full copy assigned to him, with all the navigation properties and all created.

I know that in entity framework 4.1 and later version i could use de **AsNoTracking** and then just add it, but i don't know how to do it in entity framework 4.0. 
Is there any easy way?

Edit: Thanks to what @PanagiotisKanavos said i realized that what i really wanted was to detach the entity.
It kind of solved my problem but not completly, doing:

```
ctx.Set.Detach(entity)
```

Detached the entity but i lost all the associations, so any idea how to detach the rest of the association graph?

**Update**:
After a lot of experiments i've run out of ideas, i've tried to deep clone, and detatch but when i Add i gives me and exception.

If i only detach i lose all associations so any idea ?

Comment: This could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249633/deep-clone-using-entity-framework

Comment: Deep cloning has nothing to do with Entity Framework or databases, it's only about objects. It also won't create any *new* records, as the entity IDs will remain the same. It will only result in updating the existing records

Comment: Is the actual question how to detach objects in EF 4? You don't need `AsNoTracking` to do this, you can use `ObjectContext.Detach` on all related objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, you are right it's not deep cloning what i want (I used becuase i did't know the right term), well I want to create a copy of the data, to later store it in the database. But i need to have a copy of the associations (and all the data). The thing is i know with AsNotracking i cound modified de objected and then add it as a new object (or that is my undersdanding)

Comment: `AsNoTracking` creates detached objects and can load an entire detached graph (which is what you want). You can detach objects with `Detach` *but* you have to do it individually for each related object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If i undestood you correctly, you mean that i'll have to detatch every association manually?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class `[Serializable]` and include

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
```

Then

```
public static T DeepCopy<T>(T objectToCopy)
{
 using (var memStr = new MemoryStream())
 {
   var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   binFormatter.Serialize(memStr, objectToCopy);
   memStr.Position = 0;
   return (T) formatter.Deserialize(memStr);
 }
}
```

Comment: The OP seems to want to create a copy of the data. A deep clone of the object won't do that, as it will retain the same keys.