# How can I deep clone an entity and avoid errors caused by navigation properties?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, clone, deep-copy

The navigation properties on my entity are causing my deep clone to fail with the error:

> "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager"

Background:

Users want to be able to clone a parent record and all its associated child records. I'm able to clone the parent entity alone (with no errors) using this simple technique:

```
_context.Detach(currentParentEntity);
_context.AddToParentEntities(currentParentEntity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I found that solution and another working shallow clone technique (from diamandiev) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185155/cloning-data-on-entity-framework).

Since what I really need is a deep copy I've tried implementing the serialization cloning technique shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251277/net-deep-cloning-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-that) and [here](http://naspinski.net/post/Cloning-an-Entity-in-Linq-to-Entities.aspx). My calling code looks like this:

```
ParentEntity clonedParentEntity = (ParentEntity)DeepClone(currentParentEntity);
_context.Detach(currentParentEntity);
clonedParentEntity.EntityKey = null;
_context.AddToParentEntities(clonedParentEntity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This code only works when cloning a currentParentEntity with no child entities (referenced in navigation properties). If child entites exist I get the "object with the same key already exists" error. Why? **How can I deep clone both a parent entity and it's associated child entities then save the cloned record without any errors?**

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For the complete accepted answer read Ladislav Mrnka's answer **plus the comments**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really used serialization you cloned both parent and child entities - that is not your problem. Your problem is calling `Detach` because it will remove only single entity you are detaching (not its children). So the error is caused by adding children with same keys already tracked by the context.

Comment: That makes sense. Now I could use some help with how to detach the child entities and then save the cloned record without errors. Any suggestions on where I might find a good code sample? The samples I've found are incomplete.

Comment: There is probably not such a sample. The easiest way is create clone and add it to a new instance of the context.

Comment: Using a new context works. Thanks! After calling SaveChanges with the new context I re-query the original context to display the cloned record. I had to be sure to call Dispose on the new context or I got an error while modifying the new record: "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects." Context.Dispose was needed on the new context even though I declared it in a Using statement. Problem solved. StackOverflow rocks!

Comment: @DeveloperDan Can you show the working example? and the extension method you are using please.