# Make a Clone of My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, clone, serializable, my.settings

VB2012: I am trying to make a clone (not a copy) of the My.Settings class. I tried the DeepClone function found here on SO

```
Public Function DeepClone(Of T)(ByVal a As T) As T
    Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
        formatter.Serialize(stream, a)
        stream.Position = 0
        Return DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(stream), T)
    End Using
End Function
```

but it results in an exception

> Type 'MyCompany.MyDept.TestApp.My.MySettings' in Assembly
>   'TestApp, Version=10.1.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Being the settings are a class and saved as XML there must be a way to clone them or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

~AGP

Comment: The way you're cloning it is via Binary Serialization, which requires the `Serializable` attribute so that it can serialize all non-public fields. XML serialization only serializes the public fields which is why it doesn't require that attribute.

Comment: Isn't shallow cloning sufficient for you?

Comment: Ok is there a sample I can follow. I will try anything.

Comment: `My.Settings.MemberwiseClone()` would create a shallow copy (if such method exists for `My.Settings`).

Comment: That doesn't exist for My.Settings.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to not use BinaryFormatter. Use XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, or JsonSerializer instead.

(In general the `Serializable` attribute and the things that use it are deprecated.)

Comment: Tried the XML approach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251277/net-deep-cloning-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-that and it says "MyCompany.MyDept.TestApp.My.MySettings is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.". So will try another approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need a "copy" of the settings.  Since `My.Settings` is a `Shared` property, the settings it contains are globally accessible.  However, since it loads all of its settings from the configuration files the first time a setting property is read, if you really need a second copy in memory, you could just create a new instance of the `MySettings` class and let it populate itself from file again.  For instance, if you had a `String` setting called `ClientName`, you could do something like this:

```
Dim copy As New My.MySettings()
Dim clientName As String = copy.ClientName
```